# Div fill image bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div that divides in two, in the left side I put an image, but the image wont't fill the whole space. How can it be filled, if you can see there is an space on the sides. I use bootstrap, but any solution in css will be perfect too.

```
         <div
            class="shadow-box d-flex flex-row overflow-hidden"
            style="height: 205px"
          >
            <div class="col-4 overflow-hidden">
              <img src="../../assets/img/bav1.png" alt="" class="h-100" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 p-4">
              <div class="col-10">
                <p class="font-TolyerBold1 fs-24 fs-md-26">
                  Como Mejorar mi Bienestar
                </p>
              </div>
              <p class="fs-12 fs-md-14">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Iusto debitis ullam sunt repellat nobis
              </p>
            </div>
            <img
              src="../../assets/img/iconork.png"
              alt=""
              class="tag p-3 p-md-4"
            />
          </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want, you may leave the width and height attributes off the image to maintain aspect ratio and use flexbox to do the centering for you.

```
.fill {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden
}
.fill img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%
}
<div class="fill">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/320/240" alt="" />
</div>
```

I tested this successfully in IE9, Chrome 31, and Opera 18. But no other browsers were tested. As always you must consider your particular support requirements.

This works but may not work in your case:

```
img {
   object-fit: cover;
   width: 50px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The first solution you gave me is just perfect.